# How can I align text in a cell to the top with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, alignment, cell, openpyxl

I want the text in an Excel cell to align with the top, rather then with the bottom, when writing a file from python using openpyxl

Comment: Where is your try? Please add your code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sheet["A1"].alignment.vertical = "top"
```

Comment: remember style objects are immutable and cannot be changed. Reassign the style with a copy

Answer (score 6):

This works for me. I am using openpyxl v2.5.8.

```
new_cell.alignment=Alignment(horizontal='general',
                     vertical='top',
                     text_rotation=0,
                     wrap_text=False,
                     shrink_to_fit=False,
                     indent=0)
```

For more info: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html?highlight=cell%20alignment

Answer (score 1):

Use two loops to apply the alignment format to each cell.

```py
al = Alignment(horizontal="left", vertical="top")
for row in sheet['A1':'A2']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.alignment = al
```

This idea comes from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/GDrfknwrYEM

Comment: Hi, this answer was in the low-quality review queue.  Code-only answers may solve the question but they are much more useful if you explain why they are correct. The community benefits from theory as well as code to understand your answer fully.

Answer (score 0):

You set the cell `style.alignment.vertical` to a desired value. For example, to make the cell `A1` to vertically align up:

```
# ws is worksheet
myCell = ws.cell('A1')
myCell.style.alignment.vertical = Alignment.VERTICAL_TOP
```

Find more details on the class reference page [here](http://openpyxl.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.5.5-1/classopenpyxl_1_1style_1_1Alignment.html).

Comment: This statement didn't seem to work for me, I don't know why, but the answer above did work. Thanks for your response

Comment: No problem. Maybe you ignored the comment saying that ws is a worksheet. But the important thing is you got it working.

Comment: also currentCell is None

Comment: AttributeError("Style objects are immutable and cannot be changed."                             AttributeError: Style objects are immutable and cannot be changed.Reassign the style with a copy